# When using VirtualBox, is it better to use the VirtualBox encryption or the OS disk encryption?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, virtualization, file-encryption, virtualbox

VirtualBox has an option to encrypt the drive of a VM.

When I installed Debian or Ubuntu, I have the option to say that I want the full disk encrypted.

I'm thinking that both do pretty much the same thing in this situation and they are not both required.

However, the VirtualBox encryption, I would imagine, also prevents preying eyes of the file representing the VM disk residing on the Host system. So that would mean a little more of the data is hidden and makes that VM's system overall safer.

Is that assumption correct?

Would there be an advantage in having both encryptions active (VirtualBox and OS full disk encryption)?

Comment: I would prefer Virtualbox encryption as it prevents any modification of the disk when the VM is off. But if this is really necessary depends on the potential attacks and threads you are facing.

Comment: Related:  ["VirtualBox Disk Encryption vs. Ubuntu VM Disk Encryption"](https://superuser.com/questions/1445735/virtualbox-disk-encryption-vs-ubuntu-vm-disk-encryption), SuperUser.

Comment: @Nat Although I pretty much never use the "save VM state" feature, but that's an interesting side effect of using that feature and not getting encryption... (since I would imagine VirtualBox would just save the RAM as is).